# Search string with space in a long text in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to hear from anyone who has a solid structural solution for settings and mapping for an index that will have fields with long text where I can search with spaces.

According to my knowledge, field type must keywords then I can use **wildcard**, which is not suggested for long text because it will be expensive.

However, is it true?

Thanks,
emsi

Comment: You should try to use [`match_prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) and [`match_phrase_prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) which should do the job.

Comment: Currently, I am using match_phrase_prefix and it just works without changing the mapping, however, there is a catch. When I search for "coffee b then I get "Caffee Bean ...", which is perfect but "Caffee - Bean" is the result too. 
Should also I use a custom analyzer?
I have already tried different options that the query presents.

Comment: Yes, you will need custom analyzer if you want to preserve `-`. It is removed by `standard` analyzer for `text` fields

Comment: Now it is handled by using a custom analyzer. Thanks.